# How to debug instantiation failure when regsvr32 succeeds

Tags: debugging, dll, instantiation

My DLL uses and I've statically linked to msvcr110, msvcp110 and atl110.  Regsvr32 succeeds.  However when I goto instantiate via progid I get the error:

Runtime Error: Automation server can't create object

How can I determine what is causing the problem?

Comment: What flavor of Windows are you developing in? Sounds like it might be a 32-bit/64-bit problem...

Comment: Use SysInternals' ProcMon to see the program search for registry keys and files.

Comment: Dave - Thanks for the insight.  This turned out to be a 32/64-bit issue.  I've built 32/64 bit versions of the DLL, problem solved.  Curious if it's possible to build a single DLL that will work on both architectures?